# VBA: interpeting English date format as string

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a spreadsheet containing dates in English format:

```
12 Feb 2015
13 Oct 2016
etc.
```

However, since my MS Excel is in French, it doesn't take them as dates but rather as strings.

I need to do some parsing with those values, so I run my procedure but something annoying happens. VBA, set in English no matter the OS/Microsoft language, gets the `12 Feb 2015` as a date and so, when I print it back, it returns me the French date (`12-févr-2015`, read as `12/02/2015`). This stops me comparing that value with the previous `12 Feb 2015`.

Is there anyway I can ask VBA not to take the initiative of interpreting my string as a date?

Here is a simplified version of my code + test case (but I guess you won't be able to see the issue if running it on an English Excel):

1. Put the string `12 Feb 2015` in the Range A1 of your spreadsheet
2. Run the following code:

   ```
   Sub test()
       myVal = Range("A1").Value
       Range("A2").Value = myVal
   End Sub
   ```
3. The value in Range("A2") will be a date in your Excel language, and not a string as it was before.

**Note:** I have thought of writing `Range("A2").Value = "'" & myVal` to let the value be a `String` instead of a date, but it doesn't make me possible to later compare `12 Feb 2015` with `'12 Feb 2015` and, anyway, `12 Feb 2015` becomes a date already when it's read by `myVal = Range("A1").Value`.

Comment: Does it really takes `12-févr-2015` and makes it `12/05/2015` or this is technical error in writing it?

Comment: Your example code uses a Variant - if you want to control the way the value is interpreted then you need to control the data type of the variables you're using.

Comment: @Vityata what I meant is that you see `12-févr-2015` in the cell, but if you press F2 to check the value it will be `12/02/2015`. May instead of February is a typing error, will change it right now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retain the string, just use `Text` in place of `Value`, and define the storage variable as a string. Like so

```
Sub test()
    Dim myVal as String
    myVal = Range("A1").Text
    Range("A2").Value = myVal
End Sub
```

`Text` is read only, so still using `Value` to write to the new cell. Docs which include an example for the difference between `Value` and `Text`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx

Comment: Thanks Wolfie, will try to make a declaration (the problem is that this variable is mixed with others and I don't get at which point of the game it turns to date) and will accept your answer if it works!

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, it should work without the declaration, but it's always a good habit to declare things! The declaration won't force the format, that's done by `.Text`, it just makes things more obvious to the compiler and the programmer!